# React bootstrap navbar border

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, navbar, react-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap in my react project (ReactJS) and I have this border on my navbar :
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/li6Gt.png)

I can't find how to remove it...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the class

```
shadow-none
```

in your component or else try

```
z-depth-0
```

Comment: Could you accept the answer so that others can find it easy to get the solution

Comment: Yes but i cant vote because i have less 15 point of reputation....